# Is there a wordpress plugin to present all photos in a post

Tags: php, wordpress

... in a gallery type of way.  I want all the pics in my post to be presented in a gallery. I already have posts submitted, but what I am looking for is a plugin that would take all the images in the post and present them as a gallary. Is there such a plugin?

**update:**

```
<img id="breeOne" src="http://www.frontpagejunky.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/charlie-olson3.jpg" alt="" width="150px" height="150px" />
```

[nggallery id="breeOne"]
[nggallery id="breeTwo"]
[nggallery id="breeThree"]
[nggallery id="breeFour"]

here is my update
above... that doesnt work

Comment: Why not use the built-in WordPress galleries? Simply upload images into your post and add the [gallery] shortcode to display them. http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert gallery into your posts check `NextGEN` Gallery at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

This plugin appends gallery option to the `wordpress` post editor under visual tab.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: so basically I use this shortcode:  [nggallery id=x].. i have a few external links and not id, would it still work

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd yes man u can add that too check the FAQ section --http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/faq/ Can I add an external links to galleries?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd bro little confused :( plz chk this link if ur trying to hack the plugin files http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-link-nextgen-gallery-images-to-an-individual-page-or-post-in-wordpress/  and let me know

Comment: I just want to make a gallery out of random images that i provide it:... example: <img src="google.com/goog1.jpg" />,<img src="google.com/goog2.jpg" />,<img src="google.com/goog3.jpg" />,<img src="google.com/goog4.jpg" />

Comment: I dont even have this option as part of my plugin :  Go to Gallery > Options > Effects > Set Javascript Thumbnail Effect to ‘None’